# Managing a bond fund: Simulating the maximum of correlated normal variates

Tags: probability, simulation

Two rating agencies score the safety of bonds in a particular population on separate standard normal scales. Because the two agencies take some of the same factors into account in their ratings, the correlation between the scores of the two agencies is $\rho = 0.8.$

A bond fund manager will consider a particular bond from this population for her bond fund only if at least one of the agencies gives it a score of 1.25 or greater. According to this criterion, what proportion of the bonds is eligible for consideration?

Our initial answer to this question implements the method
mentioned in another Problem on this site (see
[using conditional distribution to simulate joint](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1565263)).
Although some method of simulation or numerical integration is required,
this is only one possible method among many;
demonstrations of alternative methods are welcome.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To model this situation explicitly, suppose $(X, Y)$ have a bivariate normal with zero means, unit variances, and correlation $\rho = 0.8.$ With $W = \max(X, Y)$ we wish to use simulation to evaluate $P\{W > 1.25\}$.

We can use the marginal distribution $X \sim Norm(0, 1)$ together with the conditional distribution
$Y | X = x \sim Norm(\rho x, \sigma),$ where $\rho = 0.8$ and
$\sigma = \sqrt{1 - \rho^2},$
to simulate the bivariate distribution. From there, we can use a simple program in R to simulate the distribution of $W,$ and approximate the desired probability.

```
 m = 75000;  rho = .8;  sgm = sqrt(1 - rho^2)
 x = rnorm(m);  y = rnorm(m, rho*x, sgm)
 mean(x);  sd(x);  mean(y);  sd(y);  cor(x,y)  # reality check
 ## 0.0001833525  # approximates E(X) = 0
 ## 0.9974767     # approximates SD(X) = 1
 ## 0.002128830   # approximates E(Y) = 0
 ## 0.996366      # approximates SD(Y) = 1
 ## 0.7983816     # approximates Cor(X,Y) = 0.8
 w = pmax(x,y);  mean(w > 1.25)
 ## 0.1507067     # Answer: approx P(W > 1.25)
```

Answers using $m = 75\,000$ iterations are accurate to about
two places. A larger number of iterations would provide
greater of accuracy. The current value of $m$ was chosen for
maximum clarity in the plot below. Simulated values of $(X,Y)$ in the  area representing
$P(W > 1.25) \approx  0.15$ are plotted in dark blue.

[image]

Once we have the joint normal distribution, it is easy to estimate the
proportion of the bonds that satisfy other criteria: for example
(i) average score exceeds 1.25 (a little more than 9%) and (ii) maximum score exceeds 1.25 (about 6%).

```
 mean((x+y)/2 > 1.25)
 ## 0.09342667
 mean(pmin(x,y) > 1.25)
 ## 0.05930667
```

[image]

Comment: As it happens, the axes of the ellipses which form the level sets of the density function are exactly along the line $y=x$ and $y=-x$, with the major axis being exactly $9$ times longer than the minor axis. This can be seen immediately from the SVD (which is also the eigendecomposition) of $\begin{bmatrix} 1 & 0.8 \\ 0.8 & 1 \end{bmatrix}$.

Comment: Indeed this could even be used to write down an analytic formula: the desired quantity is the integral of the standard bivariate independent normal density over the image of the three quadrants $x \geq 1.25 \vee y \geq 1.25$ under the matrix $\begin{bmatrix} 1 & 0.8 \\ 0.8 & 1 \end{bmatrix}^{-1} = \frac{1}{0.36} \begin{bmatrix} 1 & -0.8 \\ -0.8 & 1 \end{bmatrix}$. Of course I wouldn't expect this integral to simplify nicely.

Comment: @Ian: The 'average' criterion should simplify.

Comment: You can double the effective number of samples folding across $x+y=0$.

Comment: @A.S.: I guess so, if I get what you mean. But much easier programming just to increase $m$. Ordinarily, I might have used $m = 10^6$ to get dependable three-place answers throughout, but the plot is just a blob for that many points. For simplicity, I did not want to include code to downsize vectors `x` and `y` just for plotting. As it stands, the program runs almost instantaneously on my ancient XP machine, if R is the only program open. So increasing $m$ would be no problem from the point of view of running time.

Comment: That was just right-on-the-surface get-it-for-free optimization nit-picking. On the other hand, if instead of $1.25$ the bond manager wanted a much higher value, you'd really need importance sampling or some other technique.